# Liskov substitution principle and Streams

Tags: c#, oop, stream, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

Does the fact that there are [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) derived classes that cannot be written or sought break the Liskov substitution principle?

For example, the [NetworkStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) cannot be sought, it will throw a `NotSupportedException` if the method `Seek` is called.

Or because the existence of `CanSeek` flag it is ok?

Considering the well known example of `Square` inheriting from `Rectangle`... would the addition of the flags `DoesHeightAffectsWidth` and `DoesWidthAffectsHeight` to `Rectangle` fix the issue?

Doesn't this open the door for fixing things by adding flags?

Comment: I think the same question could be asked about [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface - most of the time it's just treated as a regular, mutable indexed collection, but it has the `IsReadOnly` flag and `Add` can throw (simplest example: `IList<int> intList = new int[3];`)... Interesting question nonetheless.

Comment: Right. Actually I have this question because I was reading an "Array vs List" rant :)

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek: The `IsReadOnly` property of `ICollection<T>`, which `IList<T>` inherits, is poorly named since it indicates whether an object can have items added or removed, rather whether the item is "read-only" in any broader sense.  A good "list" interface should IMHO include at minimum, (1) Is the size immutable? (2) Are existing elements immutable? (3) Can this reference be used to add/remove items? (4) Can this reference write things by index? (5) Can this reference be safely exposed to code which *isn't* supposed to modify the collection? (6) Can it accept all things of type U?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Can...` methods mean that `Stream` doesn't break LSP. `Stream` provides the *capability* to read, write and seek, but no *guarantee* that any implementing class will honour it. The `Can...` methods make this an explicit feature of the `Stream` contract - derived classes must implement them to allow client code to check whether a derived class implements certain behaviour before a call is made. So, any code that attempts to write to a `Stream` should check `CanWrite` before calling `Write`, for example, and this can be done with any correctly-implemented derivative of `Stream`. Ergo, they're interchangeable, as LSP requires.

I think it's certainly true that adding methods to flag whether or not derived classes implement a particular feature could be abused - if a team were undisciplined, they may end up with a very broad, bloated interface that breaks ISP. I think that `Stream` and `IList<T>` are well-designed in this respect - they don't break LSP, and they define a narrow enough contract of closely-related behaviours to stay within ISP. Clearly, their design has been considered.

I think that in the case of `Square` inheriting from `Rectangle`, you could certainly add `DoesHeightAffectsWidth` and `DoesWidthAffectsHeight` to fix the issue, but the team must decide whether that's acceptable, or whether the addition of those methods breaks ISP. Is the addition of `AreAllInternalAnglesEqual` to support trapezoids too far? To a certain extent, it's up to the engineers writing the code.

Answer (score 8):

`CanSeek` technically keeps the stream classes from violating LSP.  Only if it returns true, does seeking promise to work.

I personally consider it a severe bending of ISP and possibly SRP, and my inner designer would have preferred something like a `SeekableStream` subclass/interface that seekable streams could inherit from.  But i'm sure that brings problems of its own (for instance, in streams that are only *sometimes* seekable)...and frankly, real-world usability trumps principle.

That is something to keep in mind.  Once in a while, principle and reality collide.  SOLID principles help minimize unneeded complexity in most cases, and generally keep OO systems maintainable and prevent them from collapsing under their own weight.  If purity results in a system that's *more* complex, though -- for instance, because now an only-sometimes-seekable stream doesn't fit well into the hierarchy -- then perhaps an occasional bit of ugliness is justifiable.

But it should never be the first choice just because the letter of the law allows it.  SOLID principles aren't just rules; they're *principles*.  They're the ideas behind the words -- the *spirit* of the law.  If you stick to the letter while lawyering your way past the spirit, you're missing the whole point of the principle.

As for the Square/Rectangle problem...technically, having properties/functions that determine whether changing the height will change the width as well, could be considered in keeping with the *letter* of LSP.  Again, though, it feels like lawyering, and is pushing the bounds of other SOLID principles.  It's also definitely not an optimal solution from reality's perspective, as it increases complexity and introduces the possibility for accidental side effects; now everything that wants to say `rect.Height = 50;` can unintentionally change the width as well.

Comment: I don't consider "canXX" methods to be a violation of the ISP. To my mind what's important is that it be possible for interface implementations to make available all the features they possess without promising any they don't. Having methods to ask what a class can do will allow much finer-grained statement of abilities than would be practical if all such distinctions had to be expressed in the type system (to avoid having to write lots of redundant `canXX` methods, an interface could offer a single `features` method which would return a possibly-singleton object describing the implementer).

Comment: @supercat: Yeah, you might not officially *break* ISP doing it once or twice, if there's no clean way to do it within the type system.  But if you now have to say `if (!rect.DoesWidthAffectHeight)` or `if (stream.CanSeek)` before doing fundamental operations, you're bending the hell out of it.

Comment: @cHao: The constrained-rectangle example would be a bit of a stretch, but things like streams and collections may have so many different combinations of abilities that trying to have a different type for every combination would be unworkable.

Comment: @supercat: Or, you could use a language that supports multiple inheritance.  :P  Or a `Seekable` interface.  Or, if you need to seek, just *try to do it* and let it fail on types that don't support it.

Comment: @cHao: The issue isn't just inheritance. If one wants to design a collection wrapper whose constructor accepts an event recipient and a collection interface and exposes the same abilities as the underlying collection, but also sends an event every time it changes, then one type will be able to handle all collections without regard for whether they support `add`, `setItem`, or both.  If one doesn't use a common interface, it would be necessary to have one wrapper for things that support `add` but not `setItem`, one for things that support `setItem` but not `add`, and one for...

Comment: @supercat: The issue there is the stupidity that strict static typing inflicts on your code.  In a language with duck typing and introspection, this is trivial.  I've actually done exactly that in PHP.

Comment: I'm not sure how duck typing solves this issue unless there's some mechanism I don't know about by which wrapper objects can translate arbitrary member-access attempts to the wrapped objects without having to know or care about what the access attempts are.

Comment: To put it another way, even with duck typing, I'm not sure how one would write a class which, given a collection, will include a `count` method when the collection includes one and not include that member when the underlying collection doesn't.

Comment: @supercat: That mechanism (intercepting unknown messages) is pretty fundamental to real OO.  It's what makes "sending a message" and "calling a function" two different things.  Smalltalk, Ruby, and PHP (and i believe, Objective-C) all have it.  Even JS could fake it if the potential set of method names were known in advance.